# Simulate a property `MyClass.MyObjet.MyProperty` to replace an old call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

I changed some references in my Rails model to stop using some behaviour (coming from CarrierWave). I don't want to break my old code. I want the references to stay the same.

My actual call looks like: `Photo.picture.url`, where `picture` was a model by itself. The `Picture` class is now deprecated, and replaced by a property with the same name in the `Model`.

I want to  use the `Photo.picture.url` syntax to access my `picture` property and `URL` sub-attribute, defined directly in the `Photo` model.

Here's my code:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord

  ##============================================================##
  ## Associations
  ##============================================================##
    belongs_to :photoable, polymorphic: true
    acts_as_list scope: [:photoable_id, :photoable_type]


## This is what Im really not sure how to do it
  def picture.url
      "#{self.name}"
  end
end
```

When I call the Photo.picture, I have a NoMethodError. I want to still use the same call without breaking the references.

How can I define my property in my model so my old syntax still works?

Comment: _"a Custom property that return a string of my own"_ – can you give an example? How would the method call look like and what's your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan  I want a call that look like  Object.Object.MyProperty and that will return a URL (string).  In my example it will be  photo.picture.url  but before my "picture" was an object with a set of properties.  the "Picture" object does'nt exist anymore.

Comment: So `photo.picture` would raise a `NoMethodError` right now?

Comment: @Stefan Exactly!

Comment: @Stefan I edited my Question to explain more clearly my  problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like

```
Picture = Struct.new(:url)

def picture
  @picture ||= Picture.new(name)
end
```

Comment: In addition, you might want to [`deprecate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-deprecate) the `picture` method.